# Cannot find build log for bareos_17.2.4-9 Debian Jessie

Tags: ssl, configuration, bareos

I'm attempting to add TLS encryption to Bareos 17.2.4-9.1 by rebuilding it with the `--with-openssl` option. However, I can't find the `./configure` options.

Bareos was originally installed and setup successfully with `apt install baroes` using a Postgres database.

The version of bareos that got installed was `17.2.4-9.1`. However, I can't find any reference to that in any of the build logs. Only version `16.2.6-4` [here](https://buildd.debian.org/status/logs.php?pkg=bareos&ver=16.2.6-4&arch=amd64&suite=sid)

```
# apt list --installed | grep bareos

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface yet. Use with caution in scripts.

bareos/unknown,now 17.2.4-9.1 amd64 [installed]
bareos-bconsole/unknown,now 17.2.4-9.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
bareos-client/unknown,now 17.2.4-9.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
bareos-common/unknown,now 17.2.4-9.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
bareos-database-common/unknown,now 17.2.4-9.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
bareos-database-postgresql/unknown,now 17.2.4-9.1 amd64 [installed]
bareos-database-tools/unknown,now 17.2.4-9.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
bareos-dbg/unknown,now 17.2.4-9.1 amd64 [installed]
bareos-devel/unknown,now 17.2.4-9.1 amd64 [installed]
bareos-director/unknown,now 17.2.4-9.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
bareos-filedaemon/unknown,now 17.2.4-9.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
bareos-storage/unknown,now 17.2.4-9.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
bareos-tools/unknown,now 17.2.4-9.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
bareos-webui/unknown,now 17.2.4-15.1 all [installed]
```

For clarification - what I'm trying to find on the web is the build log for the Debian jessie apt package for bareos version 17.2.4-9. I want to find the switches used with the `./configure` so I can rebuild it with `--with-openssl`.

Comment: Try querying dpkg instead of apt: ```dpkg -l | grep bareos```

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep bareos` comes up with the same basic info (the same version numbers). What I can't find on the web is; how package `17.2.4-9.1` was configured for the apt package build - so I can re-create it with `--with-openssl`